# Question about existance of global minimum in a strictly convex function

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-geometry

Is it true that a strictly convex function must have a global minimum ?
I know that every strictly convex function has at most one global minimum and each local minimum is a global minimum but I can not prove or disprove the statement.

Strictly convex function: The real-value function that for every $x$ , $y$ $\in$ $R$ and $t$ $\in$ $(0,1)$ we have:
$$f(tx + (1-t)y) < tf(x) + (1-t)f(y)$$

Comment: Try to find a counterexample.

Comment: Hint for counter example is: the most famous convex function

Comment: I have a counter example for convex function : $e^x$ but I have no idea about strictly convex function

Comment: That is strictly convex. (Note: it must be $t \in (0,1)$, not $t\in [0,1]$.)

Comment: but $x^2$ is not a counter example

Answer (score 7):

No, take the function $f: (1, 2) \to \mathbb{R}$, $x \mapsto x^2$. Alternatively, you can consider $\exp: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.

This statement can even fail when the domain is compact, take for example the function $f: [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ that is defined by $f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & x = 0 \\ x^2 & x > 0\end{cases}$.

If the domain is compact and $f$ is continuous, the statement holds. The existence of a minimum follows directly from the compactness of the domain and the continuity of the function. If $f$ assumes its minimum at two different points $x \ne y$, then by definition of strict convexity $f\left(\frac{x + y}{2}\right) < \frac{1}{2}(f(x) + f(y)) = f(x)$, in contradiction to the choice of $x$.

Comment: thank you .what if domain of $f$ is $R$

Comment: That's the example of the exponential function.

Comment: Yes it is. The exponential function is strictly convex and doesn't have a minimum in the reals. Note that a minimum is not the same as an infimum. An infimum is only called a minimum if its value is actually attained by the function.

Comment: yes you are right I mixed up strongly convex functions with strictly convex functions. what can we say about strongly convex functions

Comment: I have neither a proof, nor a counterexample in this case. Since you've initially asked about strictly convex functions, I suggest you open a new question asking about strongly convex functions and link to this thread.